# Hosting my own website on apache2, what information do I need from my domain registrar (bluehost)

Tags: apache2, web-hosting, lamp

I have lamp-server installed and am ready (and excited) to host a domain I purchased from bluehost on the server in my room.  I have a few other things set up like openssh.

What information do I need to get from my domain registrar and what files do I need to change in apache2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to setup DNS on bluehost or some other DNS hosting service to point to your internal IP. If you have a dynamic IP address, you may want to look at a dynamic DNS solution such as DynDNS.

After you have DNS setup, you will setup Apache to serve pages for that domain. Look into name based virtual hosting which will make it easier to setup a second website should you ever register another domain name.